# Advanced Search form?

Tags: php, search

My application has an advanced search form, which uses Ajax/PHP to query the database. My form fields are like: `Name`, `ID`, `Level`, `Class`.

If user enters `Level` and `class` it would display all students with same level and class.

Now I would like to improve it to allow users to choose between AND/OR, for example he wants to search for students with same name but either in level a or class a.

```
select * from table where name like name AND (level == level OR class == class)
```

What is the best way to accomplish that? Is there any technique or something similar to Solr and Hibernate Search?

Comment: Javasctipt has nothing to do with querying your database. If anything, your javascript will simply trigger a query to the database.

Comment: That being said, your question is way to broad to be answered in its current form. You didn't mention anything about your serverside technologies which really is important if you're talking about databases...

Comment: I do not think it is a JavaScript question (unless it is about node.js). As your database is on server, you are probably already using something on the server to talk to it? So you should just send the query as string to server, and parse it server-side.

Comment: Describing something as "Advanced" also doesn't give us much of a hint at all to what exactly you are trying to achieve. Please take a look at what exactly you are asking and try to formulate it in a way that'll make it easier for us to help :)

Comment: There are different kinds of jquery search plugins, depending on how you want to implement this. What can surely be said is that you need to use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple checkbox for refining search.

```
<input name="Level" type="checkbox" value="Level-Value" />
<input name="Class" type="checkbox" value="Class-Value" />
```

Then you can do single query based on checkbox selection like this.

```
if($check1=='Level' && !$check2=='Class'){//result for level only
select * from table where name like name AND level == level AND class !== class
}
elseif(!$check1=='Level' && $check2=='Class'){//result for class only
select * from table where name like name AND level !== level AND class == class
}
elseif($check1=='Level' && $check2=='Class'){//result for level and class
select * from table where name like name AND level == level AND class == class
}
```